# Having smoother contour plots in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plotting, smoothing

I have a $80\times200$ matrix, and I want to plot its contents with the contourf command in MATLAB, as follows:

\begin{align}
&\text{[C,h] = contourf(mat,100);}\\
&\text{set(h,'LineColor','none');}
\end{align}

The resulting image, as you can see, has some step-like discontinuities where the white part meets the coloured part. Is there any way to smooth this region with curve-fitting tool or other methods?

[image: ...]

Comment: I like getting very high count of levels before truncating the data.  What if you used 300 or more?

Answer (score 3):

Is the white part NaNs?

If so, then you will need to use some sort of extrapolation to smooth that region.
The function [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551-inpaint-nans) may be appropriate (it smoothly fills in NaN regions, essentially by solving a Laplace equation). If more smoothing is needed, you could then follow Juan's approach (i.e. gaussian blur).

Another thing you might consider: I do not know what the purpose of your display is, but you might consider just using imagesc() instead of contourf(). For example

```
contourf(I,100);
```

should be similar to

```
imagesc(I); colormap(jet(100));
```

which just quantizes the colormap used to render the image data.
(Quantizing the colormap will typically be much faster though, compared to computing 100 contours.)

Answer (score 2):

You can regard your original matrix as an image (i.e., a real-valued function $I = I(x, y)$), then you can [apply a Gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur) (convolve $I$ with a Gaussian kernel), and finally you can get the contours of the filtered image/matrix.  MATLAB's Image Processing toolbox already [has the functionality available](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaussfilt.html).